# Sqoop,HDFS, HIVE and Postgres with free form text

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

So I am having a bit of trouble.

I initially tried importing data from Postgres using sqoop and directly importing it to hive as well. Using the following command

```
sqoop import --direct --connect jdbc:postgresql://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:yyyy/database --username username -P --table mytable -- --schema myschema  --hive-import  --hive-overwrite --hive-table mytable --verbose
```

This resulted in data being transfered into my HDFS path but using "Show Tables" (SHOW shemas; SHOW databases; just incase) nothing was visible in hive.

So I tried another route  I would import it directly to HDFS and then create a HIVE table with the data.

```
sqoop import --target-dir /path/to/mytable/ --fields-terminated-by , --escaped-by \\ --enclosed-by '\"' --connect jdbc:postgresql://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:yyyy/database --username username -P --split-by id --query 'select * from mytable  where $CONDITIONS limit 100' -- --schema myschema  --verbose
```

The output file would be as follows "col1","col2","col3"......

Now the command to import to hive was this

```
create external table tbl_staging_sms(
col1 int,
col2 bigint,
col3 text,
col4 text,
..
..
..
)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054'
location '/path/to/mytable';
```

The primary issue is that they are columns with free flowing text that could have any sequence of characters including the delimiter which defaults to comma. (using rare delimiters when importing from postgres to sqoop is not enough as it user input and they can enter whatever they want)
How can I go from my data in Postgres to querying it in HIVE from the HDFS without worrying about column mangling.

I know in the example I gave delimiter still wont work as expected as the double quotes will be considered as part of the column but not sure what else to do.

Any ideas would be good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want sqoop to create hive table for you or you have already created table?

Comment: I want to create a table without having my columns mangled due to the separator. The first method didn't work so I tried the second one which created a table but with a delimiter issue.